# Proving representability of algebraic group centralizer over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, schemes, algebraic-groups

$\newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}$I'm stuck on a detail when trying to prove centralizers/normalizers/transporters of algebraic groups over a separably closed field are representable.

Let $k = k_s$ be a separably closed field and $G$ a $k$-group of finite type acting on a finite type $k$-scheme $X$. Let $W \subset X$ a (geometrically) reduced separated $G$-stable closed subscheme and $\alpha_w : G \to W$ be the orbit map for each $w \in W(k)$. We would like to show that the functorial centralizer
$$
\ul{Z}_G(W) : S \longmapsto \{g \in G(S) : g.w = w \;\; \forall w \in W(S'),\,S'/S\}
$$
is represented by the candidate subgroup
$$
Z'_G(W) := \bigcap_{w \in W(k)} \alpha_w^{-1}(w) : S \longmapsto \{g \in G(S) : g.w_S = w_S \;\; \forall w\in W(k)\}.
$$

Clearly (1) we have a subfunctor $\ul{Z}_G(W) \subseteq Z'_G(W)$, and (2) they are equal on $k$-points: since $W$ is generically smooth $k$-points are dense, and since it is separated the morphisms $g$ and $\operatorname{id}_W : W \to W$ which agree on a Zariski-dense subset are equal.

How do I show that $\ul{Z}_G(W)(S) = Z'_G(W)(S)$ for an **arbitrary** $S$? For general $S$, the argument above gives two morphisms $g, \operatorname{id}_{W_S} : W_S \to W_S$ which agree on those $S$-points which come from $k$-points of $W$, but I don't see how to carry over the density argument.

It would also be enough to show $\ul{Z}_G$ is a sheaf for an appropriate topology, and then show sheaf-surjectivity. I don't see how this makes things any easier.

Comment: Please include a non-trivial example where you calculate $Z_G(W)$ and $Z'_G(W)$ and where they are equal.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of example you are looking for. If I knew how to show the equality on $S$-points for any nontrivial $S$ we would surely be done. But after-the-fact, once we know $\underline{Z}_G(W)$ is representable by any smooth subgroup (which it certainly is in this setting) this must be the correct one, as it has the correct $k_s$-points.

Comment: No, we shouldn't have $W$ be $G$-stable. I restated the definition in a way that should clarify.

Comment: if $k$ is the field of compex numbers and $G:=SL(V)$ is the special linear group on $V$, where $V$ is a k-vector space of dimension $n$, let $H \subseteq G$ be a closed subgroup. $H$ acts naturally on $G$ with $H \subseteq G$ an invariant sub scheme. Is the claim true in this situation?

Comment: Of course it will be, but since at this point the functorial centralizer is just a functor, I don't see how to prove it, or even what you mean to ``compute" the functor. I can check the functors agree for *specific* $S$ but don't see how to give an argument or description applicable to all $S$. For example, I gave an argument above as to why the two have the same $k$-points.

Comment: Are the subfunctors  $Z_G(W)$ and $Z_G'(W)$ representable by sub-schemes $Z \subseteq Z'$ of $G$, with the property that there is an equality $Z(k)=Z'(k)$?

Comment: As I said in my question, my goal is to prove representability of $Z_G(W)$, and the proposed strategy is to show functorial equality with $Z'_G(W)$, which is obviously representable... So $k$-equality isn't enough. As I said above, once we know $Z_G(W)$ is representable by a smooth closed subgroup, then it must be equal to $Z'_G(W)$ because they have the same $k$-points, but not before.